# Powershell use a custom profile file

Tags: windows, powershell

I know when I start powershell, I can edit the file pointed to by $profile and can put commands in there such as setting aliases on startup.

I am wondering if there is a standard way to start a shell and supply a option to load a different profile file. I tried doing `powershell /?` but only saw a way to turn off the profile entirely.

I am basically looking for something like `powershell -profile-file myprofile.ps1` or a way to get a similar behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: `powershell -noprofile -noexit -file myprofile.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) , it emulates CMD, Bash, and Powershell and you can customize what it does when you start up a new console dialog. Might be one of my favorite dev tools ever.